# How to start after setting up a cluster through jujucharms.com?

Tags: server, ssh, juju, google

I've setup a kubernetes cluster through the [jujucharms.com](https://jujucharms.com) gui.

[image]

The machines are correctly provisioned in the google cloud console. I can ssh into them. I'm a little lost regarding the next steps.

Specifically I'd like to access the kubernetes dashboard (probably through the loadbalancer reverse proxy I think?)

How do I do this ?

[The documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started#use-the-command-line) talks only about `juju`, not `kubectl`.

Edit: I can connect to the load balancer IP with my browser but it ask for a password (basic HTTP auth), I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you deployed the Canonical distribution of Kubernetes bundle (https://jujucharms.com/canonical-kubernetes/)

To interact with the cluster:

```
After the cluster is deployed you may assume control over the Kubernetes
cluster from any kubernetes-master or kubernetes-worker node.

To download the credentials and client application to your local workstation:

Create the kubectl config directory.

    mkdir -p ~/.kube

Copy the kubeconfig file to the default location.

    juju scp kubernetes-master/0:config ~/.kube/config

Install kubectl locally.

    snap install kubectl --classic

Query the cluster.

    kubectl cluster-info
```

Additional information around this can be found: https://jujucharms.com/canonical-kubernetes/

You may also like to follow the tutorial found: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/get-started-canonical-kubernetes#0

Answer (score 1):

1. On you local machine, install juju if needed:
   `sudo snap install juju --classic`
2. `juju register jimm.jujucharms.com`

   [From the documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started#register-or-login-to-jaas):

   > This command will open a new window in your default web browser and use Ubuntu SSO to authorise your account. If the browser doesn't open, you can manually copy and paste the unique authorisation URL from the command output.
3. `juju status` will list your machines, identify `kubernetes-master/X`, replace `X` with the appropriate number.
4. `juju scp kubernetes-master/X:config ~/.kube/config` will copy kubernetes to your local machine
5. `kubectl cluster-info` should display the cluster status
6. Get the admin password: `kubectl config view` now you can connect to the load balancer IP and pass the basic HTTP auth.
7. Alternatively run `kubectl proxy` to access kubernetes dashboard on `127.0.0.1:8001`